# Estimate the number of sides of the die

Tags: probability, sampling

Suppose you have a fair die with an unknown number of sides, $T$. Each side is distinct, marked with a complex symbol. Given enough rolls, can you estimate $T$?

My intuition is that can do this via a generalization of the [mark and recapture procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture). Roll the die some large number of times, keeping track of all the sides that you have rolled and the number of times you have rolled them. Since the probability of rolling a previously rolled side in $N$ rolls is completely determined by $N$ and $T$, then expected proportion of unique to total sides $p$ should also be determined by $N$ and $T$. What is the relationship between $p$, $N$, and $T$?

As pointed out by Don Thousand, you can save yourself a lot of overhead and just track one arbitrarily picked side. Since the probability of rolling the chosen side on any one roll is $T^{-1}$, you expect that you would see the side repeated $NT^{-1}$ times. You can use standard statistical techniques to determine how precise this estimate likely is. If you have reasonably strong priors about the likely size of the population, within an order of magnitude or so, you can probably figure out how big of an $N$ you need to satisfy your requirements.

However, this procedure is inefficient, since we will likely have re-rolls of sides other than the one we have picked. The frequency of those re-rolls is almost equally as informative. How can we combine all the information we have to arrive at an estimate for $T$?

Comment: My intuition is that can do this via a generalization of the mark and recapture procedure [1]. 
Roll the die some large number of times, keeping track of all the sides that you have rolled and the number of times you have rolled them. Since the probability of rolling a previously rolled side in $N$ rolls is completely determined by $N$ and $T$, then expected proportion of unique to total sides $p$ should also be determined by $N$ and $T$. What is the relationship between $p$, $N$, and $T$?

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture

Comment: Is the die fair? If it is, this is as trivial as recording the first symbol, and then rolling the die an obscene number of times and seeing the frequency of that recorded symbol, and a good estimate is $\frac1{\text{frequency}}$

Comment: You should [edit] that info into your question. I agree that Mark & Recapture is relevant, but even more relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem

Comment: On 2nd thoughts, maybe the strategy used in the German tank problem isn't so helpful here, since we have arbitrary symbols, not sequential serial numbers.

Comment: For a bit of context: This is motivated by trying to come up with an empirical way of determining the number of sensible chess games. Because the number of possible games is large, the game you play is usually unique, but occasionally you will repeat a game exactly by chance. (Controversially) assume that all sensible chess games are equally probable. Then the above model gives us a way of estimating the total number of sensible games.

Comment: A conservative analytic estimate of $T$ in this context is $10^{40}$. It is determined by considering the average number of moves made in a game, and the average number of sensible options at each move. However, chess games are frequently characterized by long sequences of forced moves, where there is only one sensible option. On the other hand, there are often more than the average number of choices. Thus, such methods are likely to overestimate the true number of games on one hand, and underestimate them on the other. An empirical approach would complement an analytic one.

Comment: Of course, working with such numbers it might not be feasible to get a large enough sample. Additionally, the assumption that all sensible games are equally likely is probably radically inaccurate. So I am only expecting so much.

Comment: @DonThousand: If you're happy with rolling the die an obscene number of times, why don't you just roll the die a rather large number of times instead, and count the different outcones?

Comment: Hmmm. That's a *big* die. ;) If you need to take $\sqrt T$ samples to get a decent estimate, and you can generate a million samples / second, it'll take over 3 million years to generate $10^{20}$ samples. And the storage requirements are rather hefty as well. The next comment contains a Python script that crudely estimates $T$ from $i$, the number of samples, and $k$, the number of duplicates. It takes samples until $k^2$ exceeds the number of unique samples. Then $T\approx i*k/2$. This is pretty useless for your large $T$, though.

Comment: [Python script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtksFugzAMhu95Ct8a2milO1Zi2mlPwL1Kh9my0IBCkPr4_U3XlhYsBYPj74_5lTq2J4o2VEju1LUxjV9YP6ziEHoqaJfnuVKfLiSO9jupims66KYtsGHo10nGS5-4u5bskNrD0FU2cfFlm56zvSJE3UYqyQUa5aEg9Ea4K_3fJpEcDk4ej_xeE_zvgct0E0KiZw6GhOo56cxM4JuAewjsDJUvAhJn4HcPdJnNGlyNHqjIaXNcwtMGti1uAfZrTx8FNRy0SCyMcItjZOtnuwxHlxmRe7NVpc_PU8NNDOSea-OQfur4Fj8OU9Wk5bXURVwDXRpa7VcGDJaXvE5--55dAEDSitQ=&lang=python)

Comment: @TonyK You could do that too. I just think that my method is easier to write down.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you could do it. Let $D_n$ be the number of distinct symbols observed after seeing $n$ rolls. Let $S$ be the number of symbols, and I'm assuming that we have prior distribution for $\mathbb{P}(S = s) = \pi(s)$ before we observe any dice rolls.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1846302/244403) shows that if $d \leq s$,
$$\mathbb{P}(D_n = d \mid S = s) = \frac{d!\binom{s}{d} \def\stir#1#2{\left\{{#1\atop#2}\right\}}\stir nd}{s^n},$$

where $\stir nd$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). Using Bayes' Theorem we can compute
$$\mathbb{P}(S = s \mid D_n = d) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(D_n = d \mid S = s) \mathbb{P}(S = s)}{\sum_s \mathbb{P}(D_n = d \mid S = s) \mathbb{P}(S = s)}.$$

To give an example, suppose I know that $S$ is in the set $\{6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$ and that my prior is $\pi(6) = \pi(10) = 0.1$, $\pi(7) = \pi(9) = 0.2$, and so $\pi(8) = 0.4$. Now suppose we observe the following 15 rolls:

> K K Q H X G A X X Q C C C G X

We have $D_{15} = 7$ because there are 7 distinct observed symbols: $\{A, C, G, H, K, Q, X\}$. We now have $\mathbb{P}(S = 6 \mid D_{15} = 7) = 0$ because we know there are at least 7 symbols. We now calculate the likelihood $\times$ prior terms:

- $\mathbb{P}(D_{15} = 7 \mid S = 6) \mathbb{P}(S = 6) = 0$,
- $\mathbb{P}(D_{15} = 7 \mid S = 7) \mathbb{P}(S = 7) = 0.433\ \cdot \ 0.2 = 0.087$,
- $\mathbb{P}(D_{15} = 7 \mid S = 8) \mathbb{P}(S = 8) = 0.468\ \cdot \ 0.4 = 0.187$,
- $\mathbb{P}(D_{15} = 7 \mid S = 9) \mathbb{P}(S = 9) = 0.360\ \cdot \ 0.2 = 0.072$,
- $\mathbb{P}(D_{15} = 7 \mid S = 10) \mathbb{P}(S = 10) = 0.247\ \cdot \ 0.1 = 0.025$.

Then the posterior probabilities are

- $\mathbb{P}(S = 6 \mid D_{15} = 7) = 0$,
- $\mathbb{P}(S = 7 \mid D_{15} = 7) = 0.087/0.371 = 0.23$,
- $\mathbb{P}(S = 8 \mid D_{15} = 7) = 0.187/0.371 = 0.50$,
- $\mathbb{P}(S = 9 \mid D_{15} = 7) = 0.072/0.371 = 0.19$,
- $\mathbb{P}(S = 10 \mid D_{15} = 7) = 0.025/0.371 = 0.07$.

So we are now even more convinced that $S=8$ than before (and I did actually use $S=8$ to generate the sequence of rolls).

You could also look into using [Approximate Bayesian Computation (ABC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation) to solve this problem. There is a really nice example application of ABC [here](http://www.sumsar.net/blog/2014/10/tiny-data-and-the-socks-of-karl-broman/).

A related problem that you might find interesting if you haven't seen it before is the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).